# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob

Tags: apache, nutch

**i am following url** https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#Crawl_your_first_website **to crawl data..**

when i reached to the below command , I am facing the Error

```
bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb dmoz
```

my java path is set .. & i am having also the class DmozParser in path

/home/admin/Desktop/nutch-solr/apache-nutch-2.3/src/java/org/apache/nutch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because class may or may not be present in your system, but it is not present at required place.

Firstly, complete the below step

```
wget http://rdf.dmoz.org/rdf/content.rdf.u8.gz
gunzip content.rdf.u8.gz
```

DMOZ contains around three million URLs. We select one out of every 5,000, so that we end up with around 1,000 URLs:

```
mkdir dmoz
bin/nutch org.apache.nutch.tools.DmozParser content.rdf.u8 -subset 5000 > dmoz/urls
```

The parser also takes a few minutes, as it must parse the full file. Finally, we initialize the crawldb with the selected URLs.

```
bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb dmoz
```

& then rest of steps you want to hit.